# Automatic list making?

Tags: list, notepad++

There are bunch of pages of a same website.
the first one is
http://www.theeuropeanlibrary.org/tel4/search?classification-cerif=H000&iyear=[2000%20TO%202010]&offset=20
the next one is almost like the firt,but differs in the number at the last,and is 2 times 20 which is 40.so,the number for the 2000th address would be 2000 times 20.Now hw can i make a txt file containing the 2000 addresses which made out of the first one by
the rule i said above?
I don't have any programming experience,but
i have notepad ++ installed.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the constant string in the first line of the new file in Notepad++

```
 http://www.theeuropeanlibrary.org/tel4/search?classification-cerif=H000&iyear=[2000%20TO%202010]&offset=
```

- duplicate this line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) as many times you want
- position the cursor at the end of the first line
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow down</kbd> until the last line
- enter the column mode <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- in the popup window, enter the first number (i.e. `20`) and the incremant (i.e. `20`)
- click <kbd>OK</kbd>

That's it.

Comment: Thanks!There would be 2000 lines,so isn't there an easy way instead of pressing Ctrl+D for 2000 times?

Comment: @Bahman:You can duplicate 10 times, then select those 10 lines then Ctrl + D, when you have 100 lines, select these 100 lines then Ctrl + D 20 times. I don't see another way winthin Notepad++. But you can do all that with a small script in your favorite scripting language